# Azure Devops: How to use Variables configuring remote Repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it somehow possible to use variables configuring remote repository for azure devops templates?

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipelines
      type: githubenterprise
      name: my-company/pipelines
      endpoint: my-endpoint
      ref: refs/heads/my-branch
```

Unfortunately the following code is not working by choosing always a default branch in the remote repository.

```
variables:
  - name: PARENT_PIPELINES_GIT_REFERENCE
    value: refs/heads/my-branch

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipelines
      type: githubenterprise
      name: my-company/pipelines
      endpoint: my-endpoint
      ref: ${{ variables.PARENT_PIPELINES_GIT_REFERENCE }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variant with parameters worked pretty fine, but I don't want to expose a branch choice to a gui element.

What I really appreciate is the variant with macro syntax ($(var)), but unfortunately exactly this variant does not work.

It recognizes even the branch in gui, but the content is still coming from the default branch.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF6Zn.png)

Comment: In the pipeline job, have you added the checkout task to check out the repository resource? By default, it will only automatically check out the main repo where the YAML pipeline is hosted and will not automatically check out the repository resource. You need to use the checkout task to check out the repository resource (see **EDIT** in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the value of '**`ref`**' key on a repository resource using a user-defined pipeline variable, you can use the [macro syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#macro-syntax-variables) (**`$(var)`**) to pass the value.

```yaml
variables:
  - name: PARENT_PIPELINES_GIT_REFERENCE
    value: my-branch  # Do not add the prefix 'refs/heads/'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipelines
      type: githubenterprise
      name: my-company/pipelines
      endpoint: my-endpoint
      ref: $(PARENT_PIPELINES_GIT_REFERENCE)
```

If you want to dynamically specify the value of '**`ref`**' key on a repository resource when triggering the pipeline, you can use the [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script).

```yaml
parameters:
- name: PARENT_PIPELINES_GIT_REFERENCE
  type: string
  default: my-branch

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipelines
      type: githubenterprise
      name: my-company/pipelines
      endpoint: my-endpoint
      ref: ${{ parameters.PARENT_PIPELINES_GIT_REFERENCE }}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

```yaml
variables:
  - name: PARENT_PIPELINES_GIT_REFERENCE
    value: my-branch  # Do not add the prefix 'refs/heads/'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipelines
      type: githubenterprise
      name: my-company/pipelines
      endpoint: my-endpoint
      ref: $(PARENT_PIPELINES_GIT_REFERENCE)

. . .

steps:
# Check out the main repo where the YAML pipeline is hosted.
- checkout: self

# Check out the repo resource 'pipelines'. It will check out the specified ref (branch).
- checkout: pipelines

. . .
```

---

Comment: By default, the pipeline will only automatically check out the main repo where the YAML pipeline is hosted and will not automatically check out the repository resource. You need to use the `checkout` task to check out the repository resource (see **EDIT**).